# react native view height not changing

Tags: react-native

I'm very new to react native, maybe there is something that I'm missing here but I cannot find it.

```
  <View style={{ width: width, height: height }}>
    <View style={styles.btns}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.closeBtn}
        onPress={this.lets}
      >
        <Text>✖</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.saveBtn}
        onPress={this.lets}
      >
        <Text>Save</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    <FloatingInput placeholder='Task Title' />
    <FloatingInput placeholder='Task Urgency' />
    <FloatingInput placeholder='Task Importance' />
    <FloatingInput placeholder='Task Due' />
    <FloatingInput placeholder='Task Detail' />
  </View>
```

and  have 111px height,
and I set height styles to them, nothing happens.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When I have trouble understanding why my styles aren't appearing as expected, I often times set background color to the various components (each a different color). It allows me to see quickly where the problem is (expectation vs reality). Any of the containers may render slightly different than you expect and it may change how the children are rendered.

Is anything being rendered at all? Is the width set (or justifyContent set to stretch)?

Comment: Where is your real style content ?

Comment: @TravisWhite Thx and I had simulator debugging for that even no need to set backgrounds, simulator Debug=>Color Blended Layers

Comment: @yifan_z sorry i changed it and seems i got this. I was just confused with StyleSheet by normal HTML CSS style.

Comment: Setting background color as I suggested would've been a quick sanity check that your stylesheets were set up properly. The 'color blended layers' option is helpful but it isn't the same. Glad you sorted it, though.